# handleMessage function not being called

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, handler

I'm helping my friend with an Android app, I don't understand why I can't get the `Handle` function, `handleMessage()` to get called.  I'm currently trying to communicate over bluetooth, I have a thread handling the writing and thread handling the reading, so I'm thinking I messed up somewhere.  I'm really not skilled with `Thread`s, I was wondering if someone could spot my mistake!  I know the write function is working because I see the bluetooth chip going into command mode after writing `"$$$"`Code below.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
....
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            System.out.println("in mHandler");//NOT CALLED
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case (MESSAGE_READING):
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf,0,msg.arg1);
                    System.out.println("READ: " + readMessage);
                    break;
                default:
                        System.out.println("default!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        ...
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, mHandler);
        mConnectThread.run();
        ListenerThread mListener = new ListenerThread(mConnectThread,mHandler);
        mListener.run();
    }
```

ConnectThread:

```
public class ConnectThread{

public final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
public final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private final Handler mHandler;
public static ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, Handler mHandler) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket bs = null;
    mmDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard Serial Port Service ID
        bs = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException in ConnectThread");
    }

    this.mHandler = mHandler;
    mmSocket = bs;
}

public void run() {
    //TODO Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }

    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket, mHandler);
    mConnectedThread.run();

}
...
}
```

ConnectedThread:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
....
public void manageConnectedSocket() {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            System.out.println("Reading bytes.");
            status = MESSAGE_READING;
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
            Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, MESSAGE_READING, bytes, -1, buffer);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading input");
            break;
        }
        status = READY;
    }
}
...
}
```

ListenerThread:

```
public class ListenerThread extends Thread {

...

public final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final Handler mHandler;
private final ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

public ListenerThread(ConnectThread mConnectThread, Handler mHandler){
    this.mHandler = mHandler;
    mmSocket = mConnectThread.mmSocket;
    this.mConnectedThread = mConnectThread.getConnectedThread();
}

public void run(){
    while (true){
        if (getStatus() == READY){
            write("$$$".getBytes());
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

I looked at a couple other questions about `handleMessage` but they didn't help.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  Just realized this is a lot of code.  Basically I'm passing around `mHandler` to my different threads, I was thinking this is where some bad things were happening.  I have `ConnectThread`, `ConnectedThread` and `ListenerThread`.  The Android documentation I was looking at for bluetooth said to run things in the background because some of the calls (`write`,`read`,`device.connect()`) are blocking calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that you are starting your threads via `run()` method, that means that you just executing `run()` method on an object. But instead you have to call `start()` method, which will launch a new thread and automatically call your `run()` method.

Here is a quote from `Thread.start()` method documentation

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

Comment: So all my code that is currently in local `run()` methods in my `Thread` classes should be moved over to `start()`?

Comment: Oh, wait, maybe I wasn't clear enough, you don't have to move your code anywhere, just do something like this mConnectThread.start() instead of mConnectThread.run().

Comment: That made things worse, now I can't connect to the bluetooth device.

Comment: Where does it get stuck now? You have some exception or what?

Comment: I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in `ListenerThread`, probably tired to access a thread before it was created?

Comment: Maybe, I can't say for sure, because I don't know exact line of you NullPointerException, but what I would do is to make one thread for reading and one thread for writing, instead of 3 thread (reading, writing and connecting). So in your `ConnectedThread` class connect to the socket, then start your `ListenerThread` and then in the `ConnectedThread` continue to `read` your data.

Comment: This must have been the problem.  I went back through and simplified everything and eventually it worked.  It was probably this a number of other things.  Thanks for your help.